# How do I use the select tag with an array made in the controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, select

I have made an array in my controller of a certain model.  I stored that array in the variable @students.  I am having trouble getting it to fill out a select dropdown.

My current code is:

```
= select :student_name, :id, @students
```

I want to be able to list the students by their name, which could be called at student.name
 and I want to be the value of each to be set as student.

Any help would be great, as I am a beginner with rails.  By the way, I am using Rails 4

Comment: I want to be the value of each to be set as student.Can you please explain this?

Comment: student.id sorry about that

Comment: If any of the  given answers worked for you,then please accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select)

Try to get all the students name and id in active-record no need to assign in array.

```
<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(@students, 'id', 'name') %>
<%= f.select :all_val,  options %>
```

And if you really wants to do in array then do that following way.

```
 @students = [["john", 1], ["mandos", 2], ["kendy", 3]]
    <% options = options_from_collection_for_select(@students, 'id', 'name') %>
    <%= f.select :all_val,  options %>
```

Answer (score 1):

AS **@Bharat soni** Suggested,using [option-from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select) would be great! Although if you don't want it,you can simply list those options in `select` tag itself like this

```
= select :student_name,@students,'id','name' #Would give the list of student names in the dropdown
```